# Difference in referring this variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am confused between this variable in the below code.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
   check: function() {
     return this.each(function() {
       this.checked = true;
     });
   },
   uncheck: function() {
      return this.each(function() {
        this.checked = false;
      });
   } 
});

// Use the newly created .check() method
$( "input[type='checkbox']" ).check();
```

Please tell me which **this** refers to which object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `this.each`, `this` refers to the collection of elements in the provided jQuery object. In your example, it would be *all* of the `input[type="checkbox"]` elements.

In `this.checked`, `this` is the single DOMElement within the iteration of the `each` loop.

Comment: Is there a possibility for **this** being Jquery object itself anywhere in Jquery.x.js file?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'in the jquery.x.js file', but in the code you provided, in the `this.each` `this` will be a jQuery object.

Comment: Sorry, I m confused. In **this.each**, `this` is jQuery object or collection of elements (array) ?

Comment: in that case, `this` is a jQuery object that contains an array of elements. `each()` is then used to iterate over those elements.